# I would like to achieve CSS responsive design-focused font size

Tags: html, css

#### **What I want to achieve**

I would like to achieve CSS responsive design-focused font size.
(I  would like to fit the font in conjunction with the screen size)

#### **Source code in question**

```
li{
float: left;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 50px;
width: 100%;
font-weight:bold;
font-style : italic;
font-family: 'Modern',sans-serif;
```

}

#### **Problem/error message being encountered**

I'm writing CSS like the above.
When I change the browser size, the text size and layout remain the same and do not scale.
Depending on the browser size, the layout may be corrupted.

The images change size according to the size...

width: 100%;

is it not enough?

#### **What I have researched and tried on my**.

Searching about CSS responsive design, watching movies.

#### **Supplemental information such as the version of the tool you are using**.

Environment:

- VSCode ver 1.67.0
  -Chrome 102.0.5005.63
- OS Windouws_NT x64 10.0.22000

Comment: If you only want to change the font-size you can use `font-size: 10vw` (use whatever value you want). In case you want to change more than just the size of the text, you might want to look into media queries

Comment: Thanks for the clear example.

Answer (score 1):

For a production page or app, you would generally just want to use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries) to change the font-size. You would set the font-size explicitly for the `body` selector, and then in all other elements you use relative units, either `rem` or `em`. `rem` units are much easier to work with. You would then set media queries for different screen sizes and when those media queries are triggered the CSS would modify the font-size in the `body` selector. Since all other elements are set to relative font-sizes, when the `body` font-size is increased or decreased, all other font-sizes will increase or decrease proportionately. Media queries may look like the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    font-size: 0.875rem; 
  }
}
```

Just for fun though, here is a working example of fully responsive viewport sized typography. I set the font explicitly in the `html` selector, I use `em` units for the fonts in `body` and all the paragraph and header elements. I wrap everything in another element and apply `vw` units on that wrapper to achieve responsive, viewport sized typography.

```css
html {
  font: 62.5% sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font: 1.6em/1.4 Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper-font-stretch {
  font-size: 0.85vw;
}

h1 {
  font: 5em Lato, sans-serif;
  margin: 0.3em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font: small-caps 4em Lato, sans-serif;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.lorem {
  font-size: 2.25em;
  margin: 0 auto 2em;
  max-width: 60ch;
  text-align: justify;
}
.lorem:first-line {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1;
}
.lorem:first-letter {
  font-family: "Dancing Script", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.9em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-font-stretch">
  <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
  <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum incidunt ducimus voluptas perspiciatis doloremque molestiae voluptate omnis, sequi dolor velit! Recusandae sunt iste tenetur ut nam aperiam? Minima repellat, mollitia ea odio veniam iusto
    fugiat dicta deleniti neque fugit beatae voluptates quo perferendis eaque necessitatibus nihil. Molestias vel voluptatum eum rem quia! Numquam odio ad deserunt mollitia, est ipsum illo ex repellendus molestiae, aspernatur vitae porro saepe nulla,
    
    voluptatum cum exercitationem quisquam? Pariatur accusamus et ratione, obcaecati nisi facilis vero maxime, minus, in sequi expedita ut illum. Cupiditate nesciunt, sint debitis et voluptates quae fugit ex illum. Suscipit, quas, delectus dolorem iure
    maxime dicta quis quidem, exercitationem consequuntur vero doloremque veritatis nihil amet inventore animi eligendi fugiat libero obcaecati facere est ad modi dignissimos alias aperiam. At nesciunt, incidunt iusto laboriosam nemo ducimus ab rerum
    voluptates, quam tenetur fugit vel sapiente impedit quia ut dolores. Amet vel aliquam quia harum voluptatem quidem consectetur, beatae ipsam, incidunt nemo doloribus maiores explicabo quibusdam ipsum dolor alias numquam obcaecati magnam eveniet? Tenetur
    minima dolores iste incidunt vel? Consequuntur, in. Fugit consequuntur, voluptas magnam fuga necessitatibus veritatis quae ipsa eveniet doloribus facere, magni possimus architecto reprehenderit neque. Aperiam dignissimos ut temporibus quas odit repudiandae?</p>
  <h2>this is a subheading</h2>
  <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur nam beatae veniam adipisci sunt eos praesentium, consequatur, a accusantium corrupti, dolorem ea in laborum ducimus perspiciatis architecto nulla explicabo. Repudiandae dicta repellat
    impedit quas. Fuga numquam accusantium perspiciatis iste magnam aliquam. Earum eius itaque magni magnam error. Adipisci, unde atque.</p>
</div>
```

You can also [view this snippet on CodePen](https://codepen.io/stephenirving/pen/rNBYOab) if you want to fork and play with the units.

Comment: I tried your source code and it worked. instead of “width: 100%;” I will try using “font: 1.6em” etc. I will also remember to use “font: 62.5%” in the body tag.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Just to note, I used 62.5% there because the browser default for font-size is 16px and 62.5% of 16px is 10px. A lot of developers do this because it makes fast mental math easier when using `rem` and `em` units. You can see in the `body` I have set the default font-size at 1.6em, which changes the default back to 16px. Want to be clear that part of it isn't what makes the responsiveness work.

Answer (score 0):

Text size remains the same because you didn't explicitly set a css rule for it. So it just takes the browser's default font-size which will be around 14px. When you want responsive font-size you could try something like:

```
font-size: 5vw;
```

This makes the font-size depend on the view width. This can be fun to play with but hard to deal with in terms of consistent layout of text and other elements on your page.

Comment: I understand that it is because I did not set rules for font size in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use a scalable font-size value like view-width (vw) :

```
font-size: 4vw;
```

To make layout responsive, you can also use view-width (vw). 
Here is an example:

```
.container {
      width:95vw;
      height:95vh; /* Optional responsive view-height */
}
```

Altough it is recommended to manually set font-sizes within mediaqueries.

Comment: Using “vw” was a new discovery for me.